# Online availability of Hagahos “Menachem Tzion” on “Shem HaGedolim”

Tags: jewish-books

Can the Hagahos of Menachem Tzion to Shem HaGedolim be found anywhere online?

Comment: This question could be more compelling and answerable if you'd [edit] in some more information about this book and its author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.  It’s available here.  http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/shemhagdolim/shemhagdolim08.pdf